How can I correct for multiple testing when testing a parallel mediation model using hayes process macro (for R)?
I understand there are multiple ways to correct for multiple testing e.g. holm bonferroni, bonferroni method), however I'm not sure how to do this when I test a parallel mediation model using Hayes PROCESS macro. Do I need to reconstruct the regression models individually outside of PROCESS, and if so would you know how I can do this? The parallel mediation model includes 5 predictors (one main IV, 4 parallel mediators) and the outcome variable. Thank you very much!

There is a general framework, with R implementation, that you can use as long as you have parameter and estimates and their estimated covariance matrix. See the book "Multiple Comparisons Using R."

This is one of those questions that don't have a clear and definite answer. Some researchers never do multiple comparisons adjustments, some always do, and most probably adjust in some situations and not in others.
In your case - you are running one model, not several, right? And it's a mediation model, so it's probably based on at least somewhat strong theory? In that case, I probably would not adjust p-values at all, as all the tests you are conducting are confirmatory and therefore it's less likely than in an exploratory situation that significant results are significant due to chance (even though you are conducting multiple tests).
I adjust p-values if, for some reason, I have something like 8 or more dependent variables in an exploratory setting, and I'm running separate models for each of them, because to me, this setting can easily produce false positives.
But if you want to adjust your p-values, I would just take the p-values from your actual model and run them through some false discovery rate procedure such as Benjamini-Hochberg.
